# Carregar campos "hidden" por javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho esses campos `hidden`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="idServico" />
        <input type="hidden" id="trasladoServico" />
        <input type="hidden" id="ingressoServico" />
        <input type="hidden" id="passeioServico" />
        <input type="hidden" id="servicoServico" />
        <input type="hidden" id="valorTraslado" />
        <input type="hidden" id="valorIngresso" />
        <input type="hidden" id="valorPasseio" />
        <input type="hidden" id="valorServico" />
        <input type="hidden" id="diaIngresso" />
        <input type="hidden" id="diaPasseio" />
        <input type="hidden" id="diaServico" />
```

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para carregar esses campos com [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). Alguns desses campos, vêm de `checkbox`, outros vêm de selection, como, diaPasseio todos começando com dia. Outros, como o idServico está em uma session.

Comment: Desculpe mas nao consegui compreender bem sua necessidade, você dseja criar estes campos utiizando javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Basta acessá-los com document.getElementById.

Setar o valor:

```
 document.getElementById("idServico").value = 'valor que você quer...';
 document.getElementById("trasladoServico").value = 'valor que você quer...';
 document.getElementById("ingressoServico").value = 'valor que você quer...';
 document.getElementById("passeioServico").value = 'valor que você quer...';
 document.getElementById("servicoServico").value = 'valor que você quer...';
 document.getElementById("valorTraslado").value = 'valor que você quer...';
 document.getElementById("valorIngresso").value = 'valor que você quer...';
 document.getElementById("valorPasseio").value = 'valor que você quer...';
 document.getElementById("valorServico").value = 'valor que você quer...';
 document.getElementById("diaIngresso").value = 'valor que você quer...';
 document.getElementById("diaPasseio").value = 'valor que você quer...';
 document.getElementById("diaServico").value = 'valor que você quer...';
```

Recuperar o valor:

```
var idServico = document.getElementById("idServico").value;
var idServico = document.getElementById("trasladoServico)".value;
var ingressoServico= document.getElementById("ingressoServico").value;
var passeioServico= document.getElementById("passeioServico").value;
var servicoServico= document.getElementById("servicoServico").value;
var valorTraslado= document.getElementById("valorTraslado").value;
var valorIngresso= document.getElementById("valorIngresso").value;
var valorPasseio= document.getElementById("valorPasseio").value;
var valorServico= document.getElementById("valorServico").value;
var diaIngresso= document.getElementById("diaIngresso").value;
var diaPasseio= document.getElementById("diaPasseio").value;
var diaServico= document.getElementById("diaServico").value;
```